# Angular Custom Filter on Array.length and Array Iteration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to write a custom filter which will only show the filtered items in a table.

### Filter

```
app.filter('status', function() {
    return function(input, theStatus) {
        var out = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var gem = input[i];
            if (gem.status === theStatus)
                out.push(gem);
        }

        return out;
    };
});
```

When I use this in my `ng-repeat="gem in gemList | status: 3"` only my gems with a `gem.status = 3` are displayed. This works perfectly, as expected.

But I also want to find out how many gems in my gemList have status = 3. I thought I could `{{ gemList.length | status: 3 }}` as well but this is not the case. Is there a way to write my filter to address both purposes? Or must I write a unique filter for each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
ng-repeat="gem in filteredGems=(gemList | status:3)"

{{filteredGems.length}}
```

What is happening here is that **arr | status: 3** returns an array with a filter applied. However, when u do **arr.length**, you are not using the filtered array, but the original array, which is causing you this issue.